# CocoaPods: How can I have multiple workspaces reference the same pods

Tags: ios, cocoapods

I have several Xcode workspaces, each containing several projects. The projects in these workspaces are related and need to reference several of the same CocoaPods.

I want to create a single common directory into which I can download one copy of each pod I use, but I can't figure out how to set up the podfile so that it does treats each workspace independently. What happens is that when two workspaces are named, the second one gets both non-pod projects.

To simplify things, I created two simple projects, FooProject and BarProject, each contained in its own workspace (FooWorkspace and BarWorkspace). For clarity, my directory structure looks like this:

```
+ Common
  - Podfile
  - Podfile.lock
  + Pods

+ Workspace1
  - FooProject.xcodeproj
  - FooWorkspace.xcworkspace

+ Workspace2
  - BarProject.xcodeproj
  - BarWorkspace.xcworkspace
```

Here's my podfile:

```
# Uncomment this line to define a global platform for your project
platform :ios, '8.0'

def common_pods
  pod "ConsoleBanner"
end

target 'FooProject' do
  project '../Workspace1/FooProject.xcodeproj'
  workspace '../Workspace1/FooWorkspace.xcworkspace'
  common_pods
end

target 'BarProject' do
  project '../Workspace2/BarProject.xcodeproj'
  workspace '../Workspace2/BarWorkspace.xcworkspace'
  common_pods
end
```

This almost does the trick. It downloads the pod only one time and puts it in the shared directory below this file. **The only problem is that it updates BarWorkspace to include not only BarProject and the Pods project, but also FooProject.** The first project/workspace referenced in the podfile works properly.

I tried adding `inherit! :none` within the target blocks, but it didn't have any effect. I also considered creating separate podfiles as peers in the same directory, but it seems that podfile has to be named, exactly, `podfile`.

How can I have the projects from separate workspaces reference the same podfiles?

Comment: Why do you need different workspaces to have the same pods? Do you have your own code that you are also sharing between the projects that uses all of these pods, or some other reason?

Answer (score 3):

I'm going to answer my own question based on my research efforts over the last few days. Hopefully this is useful to someone else at some point.

It doesn't seem that you can create a podfile that applies to multiple workspaces. But the more I think about it, maybe this is the way it should be.

One podfile maps to a collection of pods. Each pod has a specific version number. Presumably, different projects you might work on could require different versions of the same pods. For example, suppose Project 1 uses Pod X, version 3.0. But Project 2, because of legacy requirements, cannot use version 3.0 of Pod X but instead must use version 2.0.

In this case, you would need two different podfiles, each pointing to totally distinct collections of pods.

If you have a collection of projects that are so tightly linked that you can guarantee that they all use exactly the same versions of each pod they depend on, then maybe it makes sense to put those projects all together into a single workspace. That's what I ended up doing.

I may be wrong about some of these details, and I would welcome corrections if so. I hope this writeup is useful for others getting started with CocoaPods.